# SonarQube ignore properties

Tags: sonarqube

1. sonarqube.gradle.plugin - 3.3
2. Sonar server Community Edition Version 8.5.1 (build 38104)
3. gradle - 7.1.1
4. run in gitlab 14.1.0

1. properties sonar.sources contains only 3 source folder,

```
/builds/top/top-application-status-informer/build/generated/wsdl,
/builds/top/top-application-status-informer/build/generated-sources/xjc,
/builds/top/top-application-status-informer/src/main/kotlin
```

2. I add excluded sources

```
Project configuration:
  Excluded sources: **/build/**, **/.gradle/**
  Excluded sources for coverage: **/configuration/**, **/const/**
```

But sonar analyzed folder with gradle caches and wrapper!

```
    e[33mLongParameterList - 7/6 - [api] at /builds/top/top-application-status-informer/.gradle/caches/7.1.1/kotlin-dsl/accessors/67aa53bd12e1adf032ac55113cdf6a4d/sources/org/gradle/kotlin/dsl/ApiConfigurationAccessors.kt:118:28e[0m
    e[33mLongParameterList - 7/6 - [annotationProcessor] at /builds/top/top-application-status-informer/.gradle/caches/7.1.1/kotlin-dsl/accessors/67aa53bd12e1adf032ac55113cdf6a4d/sources/org/gradle/kotlin/dsl/AnnotationProcessorConfigurationAccessors.kt:118:44e[0m
    e[33mLongParameterList - 7/6 - [apiDependenciesMetadata] at /builds/top/top-application-status-informer/.gradle/caches/7.1.1/kotlin-dsl/accessors/67aa53bd12e1adf032ac55113cdf6a4d/sources/org/gradle/kotlin/dsl/ApiDependenciesMetadataConfigurationAccessors.kt:118:48e[0m
    e[33mLongParameterList - 7/6 - [apiElements] at /builds/top/top-application-status-informer/.gradle/caches/7.1.1/kotlin-dsl/accessors/67aa53bd12e1adf032ac55113cdf6a4d/sources/org/gradle/kotlin/dsl/ApiElementsConfigurationAccessors.kt:122:36e[0m
```

Full logs build:
[SonarQube.txt](https://community.sonarsource.com/uploads/short-url/uwMPYE4Sqnfwm1HEdZlRcokEqYc.txt)

Comment: https://github.com/detekt/sonar-kotlin/issues/145